# Doctrine Optimistic Locking

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am having a problem with doctrine optimistic locking.

I have mapped my entity like the documentation says (I guess I think so), and my optimistic locking version doesn't increment. It always stays as null inside the database.

Part of my entity and it's mapping:

Entity:

```
/** @var  AccountID */
private $accountID;

/** @var ClientID  */
private $clientID;

/** @var Money  */
private $money;

/** @var  array|Transfer[] */
private $transfers;

/** @var  bool Account status - active not active */
private $active;

/** @var  int */
private $version = 1;
```

Mapping:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
               https://raw.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="Madkom\ES\Banking\Domain\Account\Account" table="account">

    <indexes>
        <index name="client_id_idx" columns="client_id"/>
    </indexes>

    <embedded name="accountID" class="Madkom\ES\Banking\Domain\Account\AccountID" />
    <embedded name="clientID" class="Madkom\ES\Banking\Domain\Account\ClientID" />
    <embedded name="money" class="Madkom\ES\Banking\Domain\Money" />
    <field name="transfers" column="transfers" type="jsonb"/>
    <field name="active" column="active" type="boolean" length="32" unique="true" />
    <field name="version" type="integer" version="true"/>

</entity>
```

Whenever I added new record, version is always the same, null. 
I am using Postgresql 9.4 and Doctrine 2.5.1.
The `jsonb` type comes from outside library.

Comment: Where is your <id> element?

Comment: It is embedded into accountID.

Comment: Hmmm.  Are all your entities mapped using xml?  Your posted code shows version defaulting to 1 but you indicated it's getting a database value of null.  Could be a config issue.  Try the usual cache clearing and schema update stuff.

Comment: Clearing cache gave me nothing. And yes I am defaulting version to 1, but whenever I save new entity, value in the database is null. So it doesn't matter, if there is 1, 2 or null, because it simply doesn't work :(

Comment: Which strongly implies that Doctrine is not using the files you think it is.  I would suggest making a new acmedemo project add a simple entity without embeds.  Getting that to work might point you in the right direction.